# check to see if div is empty issue

Tags: jquery

i want to check if the div is empty if so i want to add text 'empty' to it.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks SO!

[js Fiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/HuWUV/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="staff-row">
    <img alt="" src="foo.jpg" />
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum! FOOO!</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <!-- eo : staff-row -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.staff-row').mouseenter(function() {
    if ($('.staff-row').is(':empty')) {
        $('.staff-row').text('empty');
    } else {
        $('.staff-row').text('full');
    }
});​
```

Comment: [_One important thing to note with :empty (and :parent) is that child elements include text nodes._](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.staff-row')`, Also `make sure there is not space between div opening and closing tag.`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HuWUV/10/)**

```
$('.staff-row').mouseenter(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
        $(this).text('empty');
    } else {
        $(this).text('full');
    }
});​
```

*You can use `if($.trim($(this).text()).length == 0)` if you want to to have space between div tags*

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HuWUV/16/)**

```
$('.staff-row').mouseenter(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).text()).length == 0){
        $(this).text('empty');
    } else {
        $(this).text('full');
    }
});​
```

Comment: this worked! i'm still learning on how to use `this`. Thanks @adil

Comment: what if there is space inside the `div`? is there a way to work around that?

Comment: I have added solution for space between div tags.

Comment: thanks! this helped me a lot. i appreciate your time and knowledge on this.